Closing an old LinkedIn account that I no longer have access to
In high school, I made a LinkedIn account using my school email and don't remember the password. I graduated three years ago and no longer have access to my high school email. Now, I want to make a more professional LinkedIn account but the old one is still there. How do I cancel the old account?

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?
